# Desmos sin wave sum shows different to code

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-transform, desmos

I have followed The Coding Train's Discrete Fourier Transformation series, and added a feature which spits out the coefficients of the equation.

I wrote test in the program, which looked nice. However, when I plugged in the coefficients into Desmos, these were the results (all attempts were messy):

Program:

[image]

Desmos:

[image]

I believe the error is related to the function in desmos / wrong data shift, however I am unable to fix this. The data seems to be lining up in similar spaces in all of my attempts.

Q & A:

- The data from the program seems to be correct
- The data is not heavily modified from the original program, as it is clearly not the issue
- The data is transferred to desmos simply by copying and pasting the results from the console
- The desmos formula can be found in the top left of the image

The Coding Train : Code (unmodified)

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_vKzcgpfvU

EDIT:

If there is another way of generating the circles so that this may work, please feel free to respond. Any help whatsoever is always appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the link for your desmos graph?

Comment: @Einsteinium I didn't have the file saved but I managed to reassemble it here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zptburaxu2

Comment: ** But set the bound for t to be 0<t<2pi -- I forgot to do that in the updated version.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being a _bit_ late, but the epicycles in the first image get successively smaller and smaller, while the size of the circles described in your graph (`a`, from what I can tell) are spread about randomly

Comment: @Einsteinium perfect timing ; ). Is this just a matter of reordering, do you think?

Comment: then you get [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6dsuhlva76)...